# Get the list of Feature layer which contains a specific layer

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to get the list of Feature layers which contains the specific layer named WETTBEWERBER in my portal, the code runs fine but there is no results printed out,

What am I doing wrong here?

**config.json**

```
{
  "url": "https://url/portal/",
  "username": "user",
  "password":"pass",
  "query": "title: WETTBEWERBER",
  "item_type": "Feature Service",
  "max_items": 400
}
```

**json_reader.py**

```
import json

class JsonReader:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename    

    def read_json_file(self):
        with open(self.filename) as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        return data

    def get_config(self, config):
        loaded_json = self.read_json_file()
        config = loaded_json[config]
        return config
```

**portal_connection.py**

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

class PortalConnection:
    def __init__(self, url, username, password):
        self.url = url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def connect(self, query, layer, max_items):
        # Connection to ArcGIS Enterprise using a built-in account
        print("Portal for ArcGIS as a built in user")
        gis_portal = GIS(self.url, self.username, self.password)
        print("Logged in as: " + gis_portal.properties.user.username)
        return gis_portal, query, layer, max_items
```

**Esri_api.py**

```
class EsriApi:

    def __init__(self, portal, item_type, query, max_items):
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.query_ = query
        self.portal = portal
        self.max_items = max_items

    def query(self):
        api_query_result = self.portal.content.search(query=self.query_, item_type=self.item_type, max_items=self.max_items)
        return api_query_result
```

**json_writer.py**

```
class JsonWriter:

    def __init__(self,api_query_result):
        self.api_query_result = api_query_result

    def printResults(self):

        for item in self.api_query_result:
            layers = item.layers
            for lyr in layers:
                try:
                    print(item.id, item.url, lyr.properties["id"], lyr.properties["name"])
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

**Main.py**

```
from json_reader import JsonReader
from portal_connection import PortalConnection
from esri_api import EsriApi
from json_writer import JsonWriter

jreader = JsonReader('config.json')
url = jreader.get_config("url")
username = jreader.get_config("username")
password = jreader.get_config("password")
query = jreader.get_config("query")
layer = jreader.get_config("item_type")
max_items = jreader.get_config("max_items")

con = PortalConnection(url, username, password)
portal, query, layer, max_items = con.connect(query, layer, max_items)

esri_api = EsriApi(portal, layer, query, max_items)
results = esri_api.query()

jsonWriter = JsonWriter(results)
jsonWriter.printResults()
```

The listing of the feature layers are coded in the json_writer.py, the code runs without errors but no feature layers are listed in the print results.

Comment: I would first check if `results` actually contains something with a simple print() statement.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I can see the layers in the portal, but the print does not return anything even in the simple print results.

Comment: That would suggest to me your connection is failing or your query, I would work back from that.

Comment: @Hornbydd, The connection establishment is fine, I have tried with different query type everything return's the results. I am not sure what is wrong in this query..